# simple completableFuture.exceptionally() not triggered when completing exceptionally()

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I dont understand something basic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    cf = cf.exceptionally(throwable ->  "inside exceptionally");

    cf.completeExceptionally(new IOException());
    String s = "im empty";
    try {
        s = cf.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("inside InterruptedException catch");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("inside ExecutionException catch");
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

what i expected this code to output =

> inside exceptionally

the actual output:

> inside ExecutionException catch

> im empty

from the .exceptionally javadoc:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when this CompletableFuture completes, with the result of the given function of the exception triggering this CompletableFuture's completion when it completes exceptionally; otherwise, if this CompletableFuture completes normally, then the returned CompletableFuture also completes normally with the same value.

If so, why did the catch of the get triggered?
I assumed me completing it exceptionally will trigger the .exceptionally() method and give me a valid String response...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
cf = cf.exceptionally(throwable ->  "inside exceptionally");
```

you're creating a `CompletableFuture` that you later intend to complete and assigning its reference to `cf`. The `exceptionally` you then call returns a new `CompletableFuture` reference that you assign back to `cf` and causing you to lose the original.

When you later call

```
cf.completeExceptionally(new IOException());
```

you're doing so on the `CompletableFuture` returned by `exceptionally`, not the original. The original

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
```

remains incomplete.

Finally, when you call

```
s = cf.get();
```

you're again doing so on the `CompletableFuture` returned by `exceptionally`, which was completed exceptionally with an `IOException`. You'll notice that if you call

```
e.getCause();
```

in that catch block, it'll contain that `IOException`.

---

You're chaining futures, but want to operate on both of them. You want to complete the original and get the result from the the one returned by `exceptionally()`. So store both of them in their own variables and do your thing. For example,

```
CompletableFuture<String> root = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<String> dependent = root.exceptionally(throwable -> "inside exceptionally");

root.completeExceptionally(new IOException());
String s = "im empty";
try {
    s = dependent.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("inside InterruptedException catch");
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println("inside ExecutionException catch");
}
System.out.println(s);
```

which will print

```
inside exceptionally
```

meaning the `Function` passed to `exceptionally` was executed when the `root` `CompletableFuture` was completed exceptionally.